# Loading a Partial View and changing the URL at the same time

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

When I load a Partial View with some unobtrusive AJAX I also need the URL to change accordingly.

It would be okay if I had to do the work in the jQuery's `done() callback`.

But it's not possible right, wihtout loading something new. So the only choise I have is to load a View?

Comment: you can modify hash part of url in that case.

Comment: Nice, can you say more or give me a link so I can read more of this? What do I google?

Comment: You can do this in modern browsers using history.pushState. See:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    //some jquery ajax call properties
    success: function(){
        location.hash = 'your_unique_value';
    }
})
```

or use history api `window.history.pushState('page2', 'Title', '/page2.php');`

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

Comment: Can you add a ";" after the string?
Thanks i didn't knew that. 
What does pushState? Can you edit an example please?

Comment: So the answer to the question is no right? If so you have provided the some fine and close alternatives i can consider and then accept your answer.

Comment: you ask how to change url without reloading page, here is 2 variants.

Comment: pushstate is actually really nice. I prefer that over the hash hack alot. Really a nice answer.